# working of jeditable in grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, jeditable

In jeditable, I have three text boxes and each text box has its own submit button but my problem is when I try to edit first textbox by clicking its submit button, the edited values get updated to all the textboxes my code is as follows:

```
function editCheckList()
{
 checkId=$(this).context.id;
 oldName=$("#checkListTitle").text();
 var form1="<div class='editable'><form id='editForm'>"+
    "<input type='text' id='checklist' class='checktextbox' value='"+ oldName+"' 
     name='checklist' />"+
    "<button id='saveRename'class= 'addTabButton cbtn' ><img src='css/ui-lightness/images/save.jpg' align='middle'></button>"+
    "<button id='cancelRename' ><span>Cancel</span></button>"+
    "</form></div>"

 $("#checkListTitle").after(form1).remove();

 $("#saveRename").unbind('click').click(function(){
   $("#editForm").submit()
   return false;
 });

 $("#cancelRename").unbind('click').click(function(){
   replaceName( false, this, oldName );
 return false;
 });

 $("#editForm").unbind('submit').submit(function(e) {
   replaceName( true, oldName, $("#checklist").val() );
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
 });

 function replaceName( action, obj, val) {
   if ( val == '' ) {
     val = 'Untitled';
   }
   val=$('#checklist').val();
   alert(val);
   $("div.editable").after('<span id='+checkId+'>'+ val +'</span>').remove();
   $("#saveRename, #cancelRename,#editForm").unbind();
 }
}
```

I want each textboxes to get updated independently when its submit button get clicked.

Comment: I read jedi table and got curious ... ^^ anyway could you please edit your question to match parenthesis? It's hard to read and I don't beleave this is your problem.

Comment: What does this have to do with Grails?